# Simultaneous electrolysis on applying a suitable amount of potential difference

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, redox, electrolysis

This question was asked in the JEE in 2020:

> $\pu{250 mL}$ of a waste solution obtained from the workshop of a goldsmith contains $\pu{0.1 M}$ $\ce{AgNO3}$ and $\pu{0.1 M}$ $\ce{AuCl}.$ The solution was electrolyzed at $\pu{2 V}$ by passing a current of $\pu{1 A}$ for 15 minutes. Given $E^\circ(\ce{Ag+}/\ce{Ag}) = \pu{0.80 V}$ and $E^\circ(\ce{Au+}/\ce{Au}) = \pu{1.69 V},$ what metal/metals will be electrodeposited?

Why can't two ions be simultaneously deposited on the electrode provided that the applied potential difference is greater than both of their potentials?

I know that otherwise, electrolytes behave as if they are in parallel if a voltage is applied across them but why can't that happen here?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is impossible to make a solution containing $0.1$ M $\ce{AuCl}$. The Merck Index, under Gold monochloride, states first that this compound is insoluble in water. Second, a suspension of AuCl in water Is slowly decomposes according to : $\ce{3 AuCl -> AuCl3 + 2 Au}$.

Comment: If you replace $0.1$ M $\ce{AuCl}$ by $0.1$M $\ce{AuCl3}$, the problem makes sense, because the corresponding redox potential $\ce{E°(\mathrm{Au^{3+}/Au} )= 1.42 }$ V. So using  $\ce{Au^{3+}}$should lead to the same reasoning as using $\ce{Au^+}$. Unfortunately, $\ce{Au^{3+}}$ is usually obtained by dissolving $\ce{AuCl3}$ in water. And this solution will react with $\ce{Ag^+}$ ions, producing a precipitate of $\ce{AgCl}$. So, in order to avoid this reaction, $\ce{AuCl3}$ should be replaced by another compound àf gold(III). And unfortunately the gold(III) nitrate is not soluble in water.

Comment: Study materials in some regions frequently use made up tasks, ignoring well known experimental facts. It reminds me often the popular book "You are surely joking, Mr. Feynman!", specifically the chapters Richard Feynman described his physics education activities in Brasil in 1960s.

Comment: @Maurice, unfortunately, being a high school student, I am unaware of these indexes you mentioned :( , could you answer this whilst ignoring the solubility part, if you could explain it using two soluble salts and how they compete for electrolysis when a voltage is applied?

Comment: @Poutnik In India they conduct 32 shifts for the same exam and syllabus, they're ultimately compelled to do so you can't blame them too.

Comment: @Priyanshu Choubey. The only way of studying this problem of gold and silver ions is to dissolve gold(III) nitrate and silver nitrate into nitric acid, and perform the electrolysis in this solution. In this case you will deposit only gold, because if by a strange effect some silver would be deposited, it will be quickly redissolved by the reaction : $\ce{3 Ag + Au^{3+} -> Au + 3 Ag^+}$. The only trouble is that gold(III) nitrate is not commercially available...

Comment: @Maurice at high enough current density to saturate diffusion current , the cathode potential could be low enough to deposite silver too.

Comment: @PriyanshuChoubey You may find useful these links for text formatting (not to be applied to titles):
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) ,  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  and 
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)

Comment: @Maurice India has ignored all of chemistry and physics in their NCERT or JEE stuff since the early 80s. And that's a realisation I unfortunately had to make here.